# SELECT only from 15 minutes back

Tags: mysql, sql

I would likt to  select text from chatlog which is max. 15 minutes old, but this doesn't work

What am i doing wrong?

My field "date" is `2013-01-04 22:50:53`

```
 select user 
 from chatlog 
 WHERE date  >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) 
   AND  room = '".$roomId."' 
   and user != 35 
   and event_id IS NULL
```

Did also try `<=` instead of `>=`

Comment: '".$roomId."' makes it look like you're concatenating text in PHP to build your SQL statement. That ends up leaving you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, and is something you should immediately fix.

Answer (score 3):

CURDATE only has a date component (not time).  You need to use NOW() instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `NOW()`:

```
SELECT `user`
FROM chatlog
WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
    AND room = '" . $roomId . "' 
    AND `user` != 35 
    AND event_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT user FROM chatlog 
     WHERE date  >= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
     AND  room = '".$roomId."' 
     AND user != 35
     AND event_id IS NULL
```